# Could not able to connect svn in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, assembla

Until yesterday, I was able to connect my svn repository in my eclipse, but unfortunately today i was not able to connect to my svn from eclipse.

The error goes like:

```
 org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException:RA layer request failed
 svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL https://....
 svn:Server sent unexpected return (500 Internal Server Error) in response to 
 OPTIONS request for ''https://..'

 Keep location anyway?
```

I have tried pinging the hosts url from the command prompt and I cannot ping the website, but I can open and browse my projects in web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a temporary issue on Assembla - try now - I do work for Assembla, it was a process that consumed all resources - that process is disabled now while we assess the situation.

Comment: thanks it worked now. can you tell me something on these issues on when and how it could happen, interesting.

Comment: Well, it was a process related to many,many updates in a batch update process that locked up the database - which is responsible for authorizing you for svn - we are doing 2 things, fix the batch update and move authorization to an isolated server.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to access the project from the browser because the browser triggers an HTTP GET request on your svn repository. Eclipse on the other hand, at least from what you describe here triggers an HTTP OPTIONS request. Do you have access to the server? Can you check the logs?

When you visited the repo through your browser did you get any certification error?

Comment: I am able to successfully browse the projects through web browser and did not receive any certification error.